# Can't compile and run after renaming form and doing some additional work

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, vb-power-pack

**NOTE: This question has been renamed.  Originally it targeted the fact that I was getting compile errors after deleting VB power pack shapes off my form, but it turned out that while that was when the error occurred, the source of the error was due to a form being renamed and ending up with 2 resx files.  Compilation worked fine until the VB power pack shape was removed though for some reason.**

I have a project which was using some Visual Basic Power Pack shapes (just the circles) for some things.  Anyway, I've noticed they're not supported on one of the servers I'm running on, so I'd like to delete them from the project and use something else.

The craziest thing is happening.  If I run the project as is, it works great.  If I, however, delete the shapes and references to them, and try to run again, I get this error:

> Error 1   The item
>   "obj\Debug\WQASymbolComparisonUtility.FRMMessageBox.resources" was
>   specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate
>   items are not supported by the "Resources"
>   parameter.    WQASymbolComparisonUtility

I'm completely lost here - What does this error mean and what could it possibly have to do with deleting these power pack components off my form?

And yes, deleting these shapes was the **only** change I made :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I renamed a form and it actually ended up with two different .resx files.  When I deleted the older .resx file, the issue resolved itself.

For some reason, compilation worked fine as was until the VB power pack shape was deleted, at which point the resx conflict manifested.  I'm guessing the change was just causing the first recompilation of the affected area of code.

Renaming question title so this is more helpful to others.